# Laravel Dusk Tests running very slow

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-dusk

Even when running a single simple test like the following:

```
public function test_simple()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->browse(function ($browser) use($user){
        $browser->visit('/login')
                ->type('email', $user->email)
                ->type('password', 'secret')
                ->press('Login')
                ->assertPathIs('/home');
    });

}
```

Laravel Dusk runs very slow with speed of 14-16 seconds for this test alone.

How can I speed it up ? Because if I will be running like 100 tests it would take extremely long.

Any Solutions ?

Comment: Most of that is probably booting up dusk. Try running multiple tests and see if it indeed takes 15 seconds for each test or if it's just the first one that takes longer.

Comment: Running just 7 tests takes 1.5 minutes

Comment: Do you use native system or some virtualization like Docker/Vagrant? I'm using Docker and Dusk tests are also quite slow for me. A few days ago Taylor Otwell showed his Dusk tests and they very quite quick but he is using Valet

Comment: I'm not using anything like valet and all. Still it's slow. I guess it cannot be improved as each page is being loaded by the tests by chrome

Comment: @Raj Do you have a lot of migrations? Does your migrations take a lot if time? I'm working on package that improves this aspect

Comment: The problem isn't related to `migrations`. Also running server manually has no effect. I've run login test by dusk in 14 sec. I did that test manually less then 10 sec!  Dusk isn't mature enough to use in large scale apps, at least for now.

Answer (score 4):

For me the thing that was taking lots of time was running migrations before each test and `migrate:rollback` after each test done by `DatabaseMigrations` trait. Here is how I solved it on my project:

1. Remove usage of `DatabaseMigrations` trait from you test cases.
2. Before starting tests call `./artisan migrate:fresh --seed --env=dusk`. I do it in bash file that I call to run tests.
3. In your base `DuskTestCase` class in setUp method call a command to delete all data in your tables. Here is what I do for MySQL (inside Artisan command):

`$command = 'mysql -u test_database -Nse "show tables" test_database | while read table; do mysql -u test_database -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; delete from $table" test_database; done;';
$result = exec($command);`

4. After above command run `$this->artisan('db:seed');`

Now tests running much faster.

Comment: Would need to refresh in every TestCase then?

Answer (score 3):

Solving your issue might depend on many things (your dev environment setup, your database or some other issues).

In my case it was migrations that were taking much time for every test. When you are using Laravel Dusk you are using `DatabaseMigrations` trait that is running migrations over and over so if you can improve this part it might be you a big gain. You talked about 100 tests. So assuming applying your migrations takes 10 seconds and you could decrease to 4 seconds, in total you would gain 600 seconds.

You can read more about it how I made my Laravel Dusk tests **3 times faster** than they were initially - https://laradevtips.com/2018/07/23/make-laravel-dusk-tests-3-times-faster/ - I don't know if it will solve the issue in your case but in my case (tested today) the gain is really impressive.

Answer (score 1):

As of [Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) it's possible to replace the slower `DatabaseMigrations` trait with `DatabaseTruncation`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTruncation;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseTruncation;
}
```

This requires installing the `doctrine/dbal` package to use, but is much faster:

> The DatabaseMigrations trait will run your database migrations before each test. However, dropping and re-creating your database tables for each test is typically slower than truncating the tables...
>
> The DatabaseTruncation trait will migrate your database on the first test in order to ensure your database tables have been properly created. However, on subsequent tests, the database's tables will simply be truncated - providing a speed boost over re-running all of your database migrations:

You can also add an `exceptTables` variable at the top of the class to specify tables that should not be truncated at all:

```
/**
 * Indicates which tables should be truncated.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $tablesToTruncate = ['users'];
```

Presumably tables specified here will simply be reused between tests, though the documentation isn't clear on that and I couldn't verify it for sure.

Comment: This cut our test suite from 35 minutes to 1 minute, amazing stuff thanks